# What's the function of a feedback coil?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I have seen many different high voltage circuits that require high voltage. A few of these circuits use transformers, however I only ever notice a primary and secondary coil. When taking apart a transformer or seeing one online, I almost always see a feedback coil, and I have no idea what they do, I can't find any questions on this stack exchange about it.

[image: Transformer]
[image: Feedback Coil Circuit]

These are all examples of a feedback coil, is there any general purpose for it, what does it do?

Comment: Can you post a schematic where such a transformer with a feedback coil is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transformer is out of a microwave oven .The winding that you say is a feedback winding is a low voltage winding that powers the magnetron filament .In your circuit the feedback coil provides positive feedback to sustain oscillation.

Comment: That was just an example, what is the general purpose of the feedback coil?

Answer (score 0):

In the picture you posted, the feedback coil is used to make an oscillator circuit with a transistor to make the circuit oscillate by itself when DC voltage is applied to the circuit.

Comment: That was just an example, what is the general purpose/function of a feedback coil in any transformer/circuit?

Comment: To get feedback about the transformer. For some purpose. Which depends on the circuit. Either for making an oscillator or sensing the output voltage indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where you got feedback coil or what this if from. A feedback coil is normally used to control the transformer driver. Some transformers also have two primary windings. Your transformer appears to have two secondary windings and one primary. For example you can connect them in parallel and get twice the current of one or as in your case connect them in series and get twice the voltage at the current rating of the winding. This holds true of the primary as well. It is common to have dual winding transformers where the windings are in series for 220V and parallel for 110V. The two in series have a stab on connector which would be the connection of the two windings. You can verify this by removing the connector and measuring the winding resistance. You will get two separate readings which would probably be the same. In many rectifier circuits this would be the ground connection with two diodes one on each winding providing the other polarity. There are many rectifier circuits that use a center tapped transformer, in this case the junction point of two windings) many that do not. This holds regardless of the secondary and or primary voltages.  This is a miniature version of how the transformer that powers your home in the USA is built. You can also connect the transformer in reverse and use it as a step up transformer where the secondary becomes the primary (power feed), the voltage ratio stays the same as the winding ratio. example: A 10:1 ratio will give one volt per 10 in. If you reverse it 1 volt in will give 10 out. Just do not exceed the voltage and current ratings.